# Using "info.get" for a child element in Python / lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to get the attribute of a child element in Python, using lxml.

This is the structure of the xml:

```
<GroupInformation groupId="crid://thing.com/654321" ordered="true">                 
    <GroupType value="show" xsi:type="ProgramGroupTypeType"/>               
    <BasicDescription>              
        <Title type="main" xml:lang="EN">A programme</Title>            
        <RelatedMaterial>           
        <HowRelated href="urn:eventis:metadata:cs:HowRelatedCS:2010:boxCover">      
            <Name>Box cover</Name>  
        </HowRelated>       
        <MediaLocator>      
            <mpeg7:MediaUri>file://ftp.something.com/Images/123456.jpg</mpeg7:MediaUri> 
        </MediaLocator>     
    </RelatedMaterial>          
</BasicDescription>
```

The code I've got is below.  The bit I want to return is the 'value' attribute ("Show" in the example) under 'grouptype' (third line from the bottom):

```
file_name = input('Enter the file name, including .xml extension: ') 
print('Parsing ' + file_name)

from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser()

tree = etree.parse(file_name, parser)                               
root = tree.getroot()

nsmap = {'xmlns': 'urn:tva:metadata:2010','mpeg7':'urn:tva:mpeg7:2008'} 

with open(file_name+'.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:  
    for info in root.xpath('//xmlns:GroupInformation', namespaces=nsmap):
       crid = info.get('groupId'))                                     
       grouptype = info.find('.//xmlns:GroupType', namespaces=nsmap)
       gtype = grouptype.get('value')
       titlex = info.find('.//xmlns:BasicDescription/xmlns:Title', namespaces=nsmap)
       title = titlex.text if titlex != None else 'Missing'
```

Can anyone explain to me how to implement it? I had a quick look at the xsi namespace, but was unable to get it to work (and didn't know if it was the right thing to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
grouptype.attrib['value']
```

PS: why the parenthesis around assignment values? Those look unnecessary.

Comment: I get an error 'NameError: name 'grouptype' is not defined' (I tried all lowercase and also matching case for the xml element).  Any ideas? I have removed the extra parenthesis on your suggestion.

Comment: Did you put the line inside the `for info in root...` block, and after the declaration of `grouptype`?

Comment: Sorry for not responding - other work came up.  I couldn't get the 'attrib' command to work (It gave an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'").  I was able to use what you suggested though, but with a 'get' instead.  I've updated the example code above to what now works for me.  Much appreciated all!